# How to modify a regex to only match a specific number in a string?

Tags: php, regex

Below is my code to replace all mentions with their respective profile links using  tag.

Now what i need is to remove a specific mention from this string.

Say i have string "hi how are you guys???... @@[Sam Thomas:10181] @@[Jack Daniel:11074] "

now i want to remove @@[Sam Thomas:10181] from this string using his id which will be unique one ie 10181.. any regular expression to identify this whole pattern using id as specified above.

```
echo 'USER TAG NAME WITH PROFILE LINK<br/><hr>';
$text = "hi how are you guys???... @@[Sam Thomas:10181] @@[Jack Daniel:11074] @@[Paul Walker:11043] ";
echo 'REGULAR EXPRESSION USED: <b>/@@\[([^:]*):(\d*)\]/</b>';
echo '<br/>Sample Text<br/>';
echo $text.'<br/>';
$pattern = "/@@\[([^:]*):(\d*)\]/";
$matches = array();
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
echo '<hr>';
$output = preg_replace($pattern, "<a href=\"http://localhost/$2\" class=\"tooltip\">$1</a>", $text);
echo 'FINAL OUTPUT<br/><hr>';
echo $output;
echo '<br/>==================================================================================<br/>';
```

Comment: Just use `10181` instead of `\d*`?

Comment: @TimPietzcker hi i needed to encrypt the user_id but now this regular expression does not match encrypted ids ex:@@[Herald Charley:ZGNjAmD9ac3K]  sdasdasd asdasdasdasdasd

Comment: Well, then use `ZGNjAmD9ac3K` instead of `10181`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker yup but this expression return empty array for " "/@@\[([^:]*):(\d*)\]/";" when encrypted ids are given

Comment: @TimPietzcker for removal we can give explicitly but my first step got broken when giving encrypted id

Comment: Yes, `\d*` matches only numbers. If you use `\w*` instead, it also matches letters. Perhaps that's already sufficient.

Comment: @TimPietzcker waaw that did the trick :):)  is it safe to use .*? instead of \w* so that it matches anything as in future i may change my encryption...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\d*` matches any number - if you want to restrict the match to a certain number, replace it with that number:

```
$pattern = "/@@\[([^:]*):(10181)\]/";
```

If you expect a variation of numbers, you can use [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
$pattern = "/@@\[([^:]*):(10181|11074)\]/";
```